# Counter example to Intersection of Sum of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

> > Give an example showing that, in general,
> >     $$ W_1 \cap (W_2 + W_3) \neq (W_1 \cap W_2) + (W_1 \cap W_3) $$
> >     where the $W_i$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$

Is this an okay proof?  I think it is a counter example but I don't know if it is *in general* for subspaces

Let $W_i$ be $n-tuples$ and take $W_1 = \{ k+1, k+1, \dots, k+1 \} $ (n-times);

$W_2=\{ k, k, \dots, k \} $ (n-times); and

$W_3 = \{ 1,1, \dots, 1 \}$ (n-times) then

$$ \{k+1, k+1, \dots, k+1 \} \cap ( \{k,k, \dots, k\} + \{ 1,1, \dots, 1 \}) = \{k+1, k+1, \dots, k+1 \} $$

$$ \neq (\{k+1, k+1, \dots, k+1 \} \cap \{k,k, \dots, k\} ) + ( \{k+1, k+1, \dots, k+1 \} \cap ( \{k,k, \dots, k\}) = \emptyset $$

---

**New Solution**

I wasn't sure whether to add this here or as a comment or as an answer, if someone could kindly let me know which method is desired on stack exchange.

Take

$$ W_1 = \{ (x, x) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

$$W_2 = \{ (x, x) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

$$ W_3 = \{ (0, x) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

$$ \Rightarrow (x,x) \cap \left( (x,x) + (0,x) \right) = (x,x) \cap (x,2x) = (x,0)  $$

$$ \neq ((x,x) \cap (x,x)) + ((x,x) \cap (0,x)) = (x,x) + (0,x) = (x,2x) $$

Comment: The example is talking about subspaces, not $n$-tuples.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought it would be applicable, thank you, I'll try again(:

Comment: Keep at it, you'll get there eventually.